# @font-face family looks different on desktop / mobile

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I'm currently using a custom font on my website. The font looks fine on desktop, however on mobile it looks completely different. I'm also using all the right formats. Here is the code and pictures below:

Also When I remove the font family, it turns into a serif font which means a font is in fact loading, but why it looks completely different I'm not sure.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'futura';
    src: url('./futura.eot');
    src: url('./futura.eot?') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('./futura.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('./futura.woff') format('woff'),
         url('./futura.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('./futura.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

[image: Desktop (Correct appearance)]
[image: Mobile (Incorrect appearance)]

Comment: Your `svg` and `eot?` types need id, aren't they?

Comment: Please try to create snippet for better and quick result.

Comment: What mobile(s)/browsers are you using?

Comment: @AHaworth I'm using an iPhone. and tested it on Safari and also chrome.

Comment: Have you tried without the svg src option? svg font is deprecated but in any case only is enabled on Safari (Chrome on IOS is basically Safari too) and as that's the last option maybe it's causing a problem??

Comment: @AHaworth Removed it and still no fix. Very strange. When I remove the font family, it turns into a serif font which means a font is in fact loading, but why it looks different I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I just had to change the font-weight from normal to bold.

Answer (score -1):

i had same problem, i remove font type and just keep ttf,i use media query for limit this change for mobile

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'futura';
  src: url('./futura.ttf');
}

@media(min-width:768px){
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'futura';
    src: url('./futura.eot');
    src: url('./futura.eot?') format('embedded-opentype'),
      url('./futura.woff2') format('woff2'),
      url('./futura.woff') format('woff'),
      url('./futura.ttf') format('truetype'),
      url('./futura.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
  }
}
```

if this wont work. add this line on top of your css

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'futura';
  src: url('./futura.ttf');
}
```